# Unable to access kubernetes NodePort service from browser

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-service

I am doing my practice on **Kubernetes** through **Minikube** on my **AWS EC2**. As part of that, I have created **deployment** and exposed that through **NodePort** service, then checked with:

```
curl http://<node-ip>:<service-port>
```

in EC2 Machine that worked fine. But when I hit the same URL on browser gave me:

```
This site can't be reached
```

Can anyone help me what is the problem and how can I access this?

Thank you.

This is my Deployment YAML file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myfirstdeployment
  labels:
    app: web
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  template:
    metadata:
      name: myfirstpod
      labels:
        app: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myfirstpod-1
        image: nginx
        command: ["sleep","3600"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

This is my Service YAML file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myfirstservice
spec:
  selector:
    app: web
  ports:
  - targetPort: 80 #target container's port
    port: 80 #service port
    nodePort: 30030 #node port that we access to
  type: NodePort
```

Comment: Hello @Aravind. Could you share your current `yaml` configs? Also, have you followed any kind of tutorial or guide for this?

Comment: Hai @Wytrzymały Wiktor , as you requested I have modified my post with my kubernetes YAML files. Hope you will understand now the problem that I made. Thankyou

Comment: Hello Aravind, I am facing exact same issue. However my cluster is created using kubeadm tool ( not minikube). How you did solve your issue please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly recommend going through the official tutorial showing the [Accessing apps](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/) options in Minikube:

> How to access applications running within minikube There are two major
> categories of services in Kubernetes:
>
> - NodePort
> - LoadBalancer
>
> minikube supports either. Read on!

There you will find how to use both, the [NodePort access](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#nodeport-access):

> A `NodePort` service is the most basic way to get external traffic
> directly to your service. `NodePort`, as the name implies, opens a
> specific port, and any traffic that is sent to this port is forwarded
> to the service.

Notice that you have to use `minikube ip` here.

And also the [LoadBalancer access](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#loadbalancer-access):

> A `LoadBalancer` service is the standard way to expose a service to the
> internet. With this method, each service gets its own IP address.

This method uses the `minikube tunnel` command.

You can also use [these docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/) as a supplement.

Comment: Thank you so much @Wytrzymały Wiktor for your replay

Comment: Hello @Wytrzymały, the documentation you referred is very knowledgeable. As I was reading throughout all those, I mostly have seen only accessing using Load Balancer that is done by starting minikube tunnel, and have seen this [url](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/) but not so descriptive how to access the service using the NodePort. I have done many time as mentioned in this [url](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/), but unable to access service from my web browser.

Comment: @Aravind I'd reckon you would need to tell which exact `--driver` you are using. Each driver behaves differently when exposing your app to outside sources (outside of your host). I think you could use `--driver=none` which will spawn minikube directly on the vm (with `--driver=docker` you would encapsulate your minikube within a docker container and with `driver=none` it will use `Docker` directly on the vm). In that case you will not have another layer of networking between your apps and your browser. Take a look here: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/none/ .