# Not able to access this NodePort service outside the cluster (in browser)

Tags: kubernetes, windows-subsystem-for-linux, minikube, kubernetes-service

I am learning K8s and the NodePort service is returning me timeout error while accessing it from outside the cluster. Inside the cluster it works alright. I have Minikube using docker driver.

I created the following deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sample-python-app
  labels:
    app: sample-python-app
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sample-python-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sample-python-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: python-app
        image: abhishekf5/python-sample-app-demo:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
```

and the service.yml is as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: python-django-app-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: sample-python-app
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8000
      nodePort: 30007
```

Now when I try to access it inside the cluster, it works just fine:

```
minikube ssh
curl -L http://<cluster ip>:80/demo
```

But as soon as I hit the following outside the cluster, it times out:

`curl -L http://<minikube ip>:30007/demo`   //Using -L because the app requires a redirect to work//

This is the python django app that I'm trying to access (Docker file is in the github repo only):

[Python app](https://github.com/iam-veeramalla/Docker-Zero-to-Hero/tree/main/examples/python-web-app)

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68693295/unable-to-access-kubernetes-nodeport-service-from-browser) didn't help me either.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I see WSL tag, did you install it inside WSL to it's installed on the Windows? are you using docker-desktop or docker manually installed inside WSL for example Ubuntu. I recommend using k8s from Docker-Desktop for Windows it works better

Comment: @zori I installed minikube on WSL on my Windows 11 Home and using Docker Desktop as well.

Comment: Did you call `curl` from WSL or from Windows? I installed minikube inside WSL using `curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64
sudo install minikube-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube` then added your deployments and everything works when I call `curl` from WSL Ubuntu in my case it's `curl -L 192.168.49.2:30007/demo`. To make it work from Windows you case use `socat TCP4-LISTEN:30007,fork TCP4:<minikube ip>:30007` from WSL then on Windows host use `localhost` as address so `curl -L localhost:30007/demo`

Comment: @zori I call `curl` from WSL only and it only works when I `curl -L http://<cluster ip>:80/demo` by ssh'ing inside minikube, not outside it by using `curl -L 192.168.49.2:30007/demo`. Still not working. Tried redeploying.

Comment: So it looks like the issue it with minikube setup not deployments, so add how did you installed it, also `docker inspect minikube` output, also what happen if you try `ping 192.168.49.2`

Comment: I installed it using `curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64
sudo install minikube-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube
`. https://pastebin.com/rNQ8KLL3 -> output of docker inspect minikube. And pinging 192.168.49.2 just simply times out unfortunately.

Comment: Look like issue with docker/WSL itself not minikube, try one check `docker run -d --rm --name nginx nginx:alpine` and then get ip by `docker inspect nginx` and `ping` that IP also then `curl` it. If that will also not work it's some WSL issue with IP forwarding maybe `wsl --update` will resolve it

Comment: Now, it works flawlessly on my CentOS 9 VM with everything deployed in the same way. Seems like WSL has a lot of networking issues. I'll try the methods you suggested for WSL tomorrow.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 with no issue like this, so it's hard to tell what is causing it, you can also try `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` but I don't think it will help much